# ReactNative - Why does my custom NavigationBar component render at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, react-native, navigationbar, navigator

I want to display a navigation bar on top of the screen using React's `Navigator` and [this custom `NavigationBar` component](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar).

I am using the following code, but for some reason the navigation bar renders at the bottom of the screen:

```
import NavigationBar from 'react-native-navbar'

class MyDebts extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'persons'
    }
  }

  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    console.log('render scene with route: ', route)
    return <route.component route={route} navigator={navigator} />
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
          <TabBarIOS.Item
              selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'persons'}
              title='Persons'
              onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                      selectedTab: 'persons',
                  })
              }}>
              <Navigator
                initialRoute={{ name: 'Persons', component: PersonsRootComponent }}
                renderScene={this._renderScene}
                navigationBar={<NavigationBar style={styles.nav} title={{title: 'Persons'}}/>}
              />
          </TabBarIOS.Item>
        </TabBarIOS>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  nav: {
    height: 160,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
})
```

The `PersonsRootComponent` renders properly, but I have no idea why the `NavigationBar` is placed on the bottom of the screen...

[image]

Comment: Did you try any example https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar

Comment: I did! the problem with those is that they always use `NavigationBar` as individual components that renders within a `View` component. my use case is a bit different in that I want to set the `NavigationBar` as a prop of `Navigator`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put the navbar somewhere else other than the bottom, you need absolute positioning on the navbar.

`container: {
    width: width,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    position:'absolute',
    top:0,
    left:0
  },`

Comment: are you sure about this? shouldn't the navigation bar on top by default? it seems more than counterintuitive to me that you need to tell it explicitly to render on top of the screen...